# How to embed images in .net Maui nuget package?

Tags: nuget, maui

I have a library project in .NET Maui 7.

Within the library I'm creating some custom views that have some images. The library project is compiled as a nuget package.

The images are added the resource folder of the library project with Build action as MauiImage as follows:

[image]

When using the Nuget package in another project, the images are not shown in the custom views. In order to make them show, I need to add them to the new project. It's like the images are not included in the Nuget Package.

How can I embed the images in the nuget package?

Comment: from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/images?view=net-maui-7.0): "Loading an image that's embedded in an assembly requires the image to have its build action set to Embedded Resource rather than MauiImage."

Comment: @Jason That didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I followed what's mentioned in [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10019)

1. Create a My.NuGet.Package.Id.targets (note the filename has to be the same as your actual package id) with all the image references.

> 

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <MauiImage Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\Images\myimage.svg" />
    <MauiImage Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\Images\anotherimage.svg" BaseSize="20,20" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

2. Next you need to ensure the targets file and the .svg image files are embedded in the appropriate folder within the nuget package of your library project. So, include them in your project like this:

> 

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="My.NuGet.Package.Id.targets" Pack="True" PackagePath="buildTransitive\" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\myimage.svg" Pack="True" PackagePath="buildTransitive\Images\" />
  <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\anotherimage.svg" BaseSize="20,20" Pack="True" PackagePath="buildTransitive\Images\" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried suggesting an edit to [@Ramaraj answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76673139/10287964) but was unable to do it because of the edit queue limit. So, I am writing a new answer instead.

Instead of using `MauiImage` in the project file, we have to use `None` for pack to work. The same logic goes for `MauiAssets` and other Maui resource files.

Here is the complete solution:

1. Create a My.NuGet.Package.Id.targets (note the filename has to be the same as your actual package id) with all the image references.

```
<!-- Rest of the file -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <MauiImage Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\Images\check.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

2. Ensure the targets file and the Maui resource files (in this case check.png) are embedded in the appropriate folder within the Nuget package of our library project. For this, we use `Pack` and `PackagePath` as follows in the csproj file:

```
<!-- Rest of the file -->
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="My.NuGet.Package.Id.targets" Pack="True" PackagePath="buildTransitive\" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="Resources\Images\check.png" Pack="True" PackagePath="buildTransitive\Images\" />
</ItemGroup>
<!-- Rest of the file -->
```

**NOTE**: The subtle change from @Ramaraj's answer is that we changed the build action from `MauiImage` to `None`. This is required for `Pack` to work.

You can get more information about `buildTransitive` folder and other build folders in [this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/msbuild-props-and-targets).

Comment: [@Thomas Carlton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2635209/thomas-carlton) could you please check if this works?